# MySQL does not start in XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2 on Window 10

Tags: mysql, xampp

Our MySQL does not start in XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2 on Windows 10.

Please see error in red below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is simply, you have another mysql service already running which is located at `C:\\Program Files\MYSQL\....`.

Comment: The error says it all. Try to follow it.

Comment: how to download xampp 3.2.2 version